# Generating tensors with elements based on position in xtensor

Tags: xtensor

I am trying to build a data structure to represent an RGB image in xtensor (a 3D matrix, with shape in the form of (WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3).
Each "pixel" contains data collected by a function of the pixel coordinates. Basically, I want to replicate what this code does in python:

```
image = [[cell_info(x, y) for x in range(WIDTH)]
                          for y in range(HEIGHT)]
```

where cell info returns a 3 elements list representing the color channels.

I suppose the proper way to do this should be using an xgenerator, but to be honest I cannot understand how to use that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
I changed cell_info to accept a `int channel` parameter, so that it returns an integer instead of an array. Then I wrote this:

```
class img_generator_fn {
        public:
          using value_type = int;
          img_generator_fn(const Map *map, const Position &center, shared_ptr<const Player> player,
                           const unsigned int field_radius)
              : m_map(map), m_center(center), m_player(player), m_translation(-(field_radius + 1)) {}
          ~img_generator_fn() { m_map = nullptr; }
          inline auto operator()(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y, const unsigned int channel) const {
             return m_map->at(m_center + Position(x, y))->cell_info(m_player, channel);
          }
          template <class It> inline auto element(It, It end) const {
             return m_map->at(m_center + Position(*(end - 2) + m_translation, (*(end - 3)) + m_translation))
                 ->cell_info(m_player, *(end - 1));
          }

        private:
          const Map *m_map;
          const Position &m_center;
          shared_ptr<const Player> m_player;
          const unsigned int m_translation;
       };

       template <unsigned int field_side> auto field(const Position &center, shared_ptr<const Player> player) const {
          const array<unsigned int, 3> shape = {field_side, field_side, 3};
          auto gen = xt::detail::make_xgenerator(img_generator_fn(this, center, player, (field_side - 1) / 2), shape);
          return xt::xtensor_fixed<int, xt::xshape<field_side, field_side, 3>>(gen);
       }
```

Here `Map` represents a 2D matrix, it is the structure which contains, togheter with `player`, the informations I want to store in an image. The function `at` picks up the map cell at the specified position (the map cell will be converted into a pixel). The function `field` generates an image centered around `center` from a given Map, using an xgenerator.